# SQLAlchemy : Insert into another table based on a insert/update trigger on another table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables -

1. **user** - User details table
2. **user_log** - Audit table has the user details in a point of time. ie, when a insert /update happens to the specific user in the **user** table, then **user_log** will have the old entry/entries of the user table.

Below are the table definition.

```
class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
    address=  db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)

class UserLog(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,  nullable = False)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
    address=  db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
```

What should be the best way to add this functionality in Flask using SQLAlchemy? I have tried the **[MapperEvents](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.MapperEvents.after_update)**, but it is not working when using the update() method.